# Python cant get full path name of file

Tags: python, path, directory

Trying to drill through a directory on my drive that has subfoldrs within it. When I find files that have the file extensions I'm looking for I want the full file path. Right now this is what I have:

```
import os
import Tkinter
import tkFileDialog
from Tkinter import Tk
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename

root = Tkinter.Tk().withdraw()
dirname = tkFileDialog.askdirectory(initialdir='.')

list = [] 


for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dirname):
    for name in files:
        if name.find(".txt") != -1:
           name = str(name)
           name = os.path.realpath(name)
           list.append(name)

print list
```

This is returned

```
c:\users\name\desktop\project\file.txt
```

however that file.txt is located in

```
c:\users\name\desktop\project\folder1\file.txt
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You probably need to join the filename with the directory that contains it:

```
os.path.realpath(os.path.join(root,name))
```

e.g. I just tested this:

```
import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):
    for name in files:
        if name == 'foo':
           name = str(name)
           name = os.path.realpath(os.path.join(root,name))
           print name
```

with the following directory structure:

```
test
  + foo
  + test2
     + foo
```

and it worked properly.

Comment: worked perfectly thank you! not sure why I was receiving down votes on this when the other question that was already asked didnt even answer my own question...

Comment: @reddman -- FWIW, I didn't understand the downvotes either.  I upvoted. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
os.path.abspath
```

instead. Your path is not absolute.

Comment: agreed, I was using os.path.abspath(file) and it was missing the parent folder in the returned filepath.