# Getting absolute path

Tags: python, django

In the django [tutorials](http://file:///media/gt0015/Data/Development/Python/django-docs-1.6-en/intro/reusable-apps.html) the guy explains edit the setup.py with the
following:

```
os.chdir(os.path.normpath(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(__file__), os.pardir)))
```

Why do I need normpath here? Wouldn't it suffice to only use dirname?:

```
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/a/51523/4385913 or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17730173/python-cant-get-full-path-name-of-file)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html):

> os.path.normpath(path)
>
> Normalize a pathname by collapsing redundant separators and up-level references so that A//B, A/B/, A/./B and A/foo/../B all
>   become A/B. This string manipulation may change the meaning of a path
>   that contains symbolic links. On Windows, it converts forward slashes
>   to backward slashes. To normalize case, use normcase().