# How can I delete the Read files after --->>(for root, dirs, files in os.walk()) <<--- with function os.remove() in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

## I want the program to automatically delete files.

## Function accept(os.remove(" ")) the variable in Loop(for).

import shutil
import threading
import glob
import os

```
def test():
    threading.Timer(5.0, test).start () # Was checked every 3 
    for  root, dirs, files in os.walk("/mydir"):
         for file in files: 
         print(file)
         os.remove(" ") #delete the file
         print("remove the file")
```

test()

Comment: You want `os.remove(os.path.join(root, file))`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to find the real path of that file to remove it, This answer might help.
[Python cant get full path name of file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17730173/python-cant-get-full-path-name-of-file)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.